# Данные не сохраняются в базу данных MongoDB

Tags: python, база-данных, discord, pymongo

Я хочу сделать выдачу роли с помощью одобрения саппортов на сервере дискорд, вообщем сложная система.. Для этого мне нужно сохранять id сообщения и id автора сообщения, которому нужно выдать роль, весь код работает, ошибка в строке проверки... Но всё равно не понятно, в чём заключается ошибка..

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    request = ['роль', 'хочу роль', 'дайте роль', 'нужна роль']

    if msg in request:
        for i in orgs:
            if not message.author.display_name.split(' ')[0].replace('[', '') in orgs:
                await message.channel.send(f'`[ROLES]`: {message.author.mention}, тег организации не найден!')
                break

            if i == message.author.display_name.split(' ')[0].replace('[', ''):
                global msg_db
                msg_db = message
                guild = bot.get_guild(831511376425123882)
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=orgs[i])

                await message.channel.send(f'`[ROLES]`: {message.author.mention}, ваш запрос на получение роли был отправлен саппортам!')

                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title='Запрос на получение роли!',
                    description='✅ - выдать роль\n❌ - отклонить запрос\n️ - изменить никнейм\n - запросить статистику',
                    color=0x000000
                )
                embed.add_field(name=f'Пользователь:', value=f'{message.author.mention}', inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f'Никнейм:', value=f'{message.author.display_name}', inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f'Роль для выдачи:', value=f'{role.mention}', inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://psv4.userapi.com/c537232/u356224017/docs/d1/416eb92aec38/rodina.png?extra=2E9CwKZ0PIjnG8aaNkwehlHwjxlycBfGx-4p20ABm3mPI4jNpdV1OXaUUA9zGA4Q04VM21UezrXsjtqC411Xbh-Ro7rW1L4OGgNxpcQv3lvfOYCb-Irn-_-51AaQa2fpNDZhHm80dvZm1HlR1ZWoDigw')
                embed.set_image(url=message.author.avatar_url)

                msgemb = await bot.get_channel(851413212485779466).send(embed=embed)

                await msgemb.add_reaction('✅')
                await msgemb.add_reaction('❌')
                await msgemb.add_reaction('️')
                await msgemb.add_reaction('')

                roles_post = {
                    'm_id':msg_db.id,
                    'user':msg_db.author
                }

                if roles.count_documents({'m_id':msg_db.id}) == 0:
                    roles.insert_one(roles_post)
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(f'`[ROLES]`: {message.author.mention}, вы уже отправили запрос на получение роли!')
```

Код ошибки:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\Desktop\rodina\main.py", line 78, in on_message
    if roles.count_documents({'m_id':msg_db.id}) == 0:
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1811, in count_documents
    return self._retryable_non_cursor_read(_cmd, session)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1816, in _retryable_non_cursor_read
    with client._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1676, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1663, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1608, in __start_session
    self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 519, in _check_implicit_session_support
    self._check_session_support()
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 535, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 227, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0-shard-00-01.gi8x6.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,cluster0-shard-00-02.gi8x6.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed,cluster0-shard-00-00.gi8x6.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62921938169cf516fdb144a3, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.gi8x6.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.gi8x6.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.gi8x6.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.gi8x6.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.gi8x6.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.gi8x6.mongodb.net:27017: connection closed')>]>
```

Answer (score -1):

На сколько видно из логов, у вас mongo кластер из 3х нод. Судя по ошибке, кластер находится в состоянии *ReplicaSetNoPrimary*, т.е. в кластере отсутствует мастер нода. Т.к. драйвер mongo пытается отправить запросы на мастерноду, которая отсутствует в кластере, коннект закрывается.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что это значит, что такое мастер нода и как его добавить, раз он так нужен?

Comment: В таком случае вы уверены что вам нужна такая конфигурация БД? Может быть стоит обойтись лишь одной нодой? Тогда такой проблемы скорее всего не будет. Если же уверены, что нужна именно такая конфигурация, то рекомендую почитать тут https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/replica-set-primary/ и может быть еще тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486207/how-does-mongo-select-primary-shard-in-cluster

Comment: Что такое нода?